# SSRS 2016 prompting for credentials in Edge over intranet

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

We have a new implementation of SQL2016sp1 with SSRS (non sharepoint version).  Normal authentication is working for Chrome and Internet Explorer for Intranet users, where they are not prompted for domain credentials when viewing a report.  Microsoft Edge brings up a pop up box prompt for the AD credentials on first access to the reports.  What setting do we need to change to allow automatic authentication with the Edge browser?

Comment: Not and answer but may help diagnose the issue. If I open SSRS 2016 wen portal with Edge as normal, no issues. However, if I open an "In-private" window I get prompted for credentials. I can;t find any Edge settings that would affect this. Maybe group policies?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is external add it to the trusted list. Modify security settings for trusted sites to match screen shot.

If it is intranet and you don't want to add it as trusted, you can change the intranet security settings to match the screen shot:

[image]

Your user authentication needs to be enabled for automatic login, which will use AD. This is greyed out in my example because this is set by domain policy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I had everything set properly internet settings - all pushed out via group policy.  I knew that it SHOULD work because I was successful in setting up our intranet site via the same policy and windows auth DID work so I was lead to believe it was a server side issue.

I did NOT have IIS installed on the SSRS server - I installed it and was sure to enable Windows Authentication.  Afterwards, passthrough auth to SSRS worked just fine.